# Run-time packge option asks for bpl files

Tags: delphi, package

So I've built a run-time package for my application. That requires some other BPLs like : `ADORTL.bpl, BDRTL.bpl, VCL.bpl` and so one. Now I want to use this BPL I've created in my main application and I also want to load it at runtime. So everytime a user does an action that require some info from the bpl, i load it, and unload it after there is no need.

In order to use my bpl in the main application I have to compile my app with run-time packages. If I do so when I move the .exe file to an other computer with no Delphi installed it askes for lots of bpls to work. Is there a way I can built with run-time packages and somehow integrate (vcl.bpl,adortl.bpl) in the exe file?

I would like that my main app only to ask for the bpls i've created, not the Delphi IDE bpls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project options, where you specify to use runtime packages, there is an edit box that lists the needed packages. Remove any package names you don't want, any they'll be compiled into the EXE file.

Note, however, that the BPL files you keep also use other BPL files. In particular, your BPL probably uses the VCL and RTL packages. Thus, when you load your package, it will implicitly load the other packages. You mustn't have multiple copies of any unit loaded simultaneously. Your package uses RTL, so your EXE needs to use the RTL package, too; you cannot omit it from the edit box like I described above. If you do, then your EXE would have one copy of the RTL units and the package would have another, which isn't allowed.

If there is some package that is *only* used by your package, then there's something else you can do. Remove that other package from the "requires" list of your package and recompile. The compiler will warn about implicitly included units, namely the units that ordinarily reside in the package you just removed. Explicitly add those units to your package and recompile again. Repeat until the warnings are gone. You're essentially defining a "superpackage" of all your package's unique dependencies. (VCL and RTL are not *unique* dependencies, so don't omit them from the "requires" list.)

You cannot arrange for your EXE to use only one BPL file *and* for that BPL file to be loaded and unloaded dynamically. If you load packages dynamically, then at a minimum, you need to use the RTL and VCL packages, too.

Furthermore, the Delphi license you agreed to might restrict you from repackaging the RTL and VCL units. I'm not clear on the details. Go reread the license carefully to check.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is the way it works. You compile either with runtime packages or without. It is like being pregnant: either you are or you are not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, at least I won't lose time trying to find a solution. One more question: is there any way I can tell the .exe file where to look for the bpls, at least I would like to add them to a separate folder.

Comment: The .bpl files must be on the system path for an application to use them. They are loaded just like a standard DLL.

Comment: If you specify a *full path* to `LoadPackage()`, it will load your BPL from that exact location, but any BPLs it is dependent on are still subject to the system's [DLL search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) to find them. You can use [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) to add custom paths to that search, though.